# NSOperationQueue (delegate/callback/notification) when operation is added to queue

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

Is there a way to know when a particular operation is added to an `NSOperationQueue` instance?

PS: Currently, I am not interested in subclassing `NSOperationQueue` and overwriting the required `addOperation` APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You could periodically check the `operations` property and see if it changed with a previous reference (Maybe with a method that runs all the time?). If it did then check if an operation was added or not.

This way you don't need to subclass `NSOperationQueue` or override `addOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

The `operations` property of `NSOperationQueue` is KVO-Compliant. It means you can observe when contents of this property change with the `addObserverForKeyPath` and `observeValueForKeyPath` methods. Consider the following snippet:

```
@interface BigBrother : NSObject
//Just a demo method for filling queue with something
- (void) addSomeOperationsAndWaitTillFinished;

@end

@implementation BigBrother


- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                       ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change
                        context:(void *)context
{
    //Triggers each time 'operations' property is changed
    //(ex. operation is added or finished in this case)
    //object is your NSOperationQueue
    NSLog(@"Key path:%@\nObject:%@\nChange%@", keyPath, object, change);

}

- (void) addSomeOperationsAndWaitTillFinished
{
    NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    //Tell the queue we want to know when something happens to 'operations' property
    [queue addObserver:self
            forKeyPath:@"operations"
               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
               context:nil];

    for (NSUInteger opNum = 0; opNum < 5; opNum++)
    {
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{sleep(1);}];
    }

    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}
```

You can see how it works by adding this line to somewhere:

```
[[[BigBrother alloc] init] addSomeOperationsAndWaitTillFinished];
```

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) on Key-Value Observing